# Missing partial error vs button not showing while using simple_form & cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm attempting to use cocoon and simple_form together to created some nested forms for a recipe app tutorial I'm following. They use haml and I get a missing partial error when I seem to have followed the proper indentation process for haml.

**Error Message:**

```
Missing partial recipes/_ingredient_fields, application/_ingredient_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}.

.row
            .col-md-6
                %h3 Ingredients
                #ingredients
                    = f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
                        = render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
                    .links #line below is the error line
                      = link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients, class: 'btn btn-default add-button'

    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

If I tab over my `.links` and `link_to_add_association` line over, the view will show but the `ingredient` buttons and text areas will not show. I'm following the procedure stated in the cocoon documention (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) but I can't seem to get it to work. Below are the full code for each files. Please tell me if I need to include any other files. Thanks in advance for the help!

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    - if @recipe.errors.any?
        #errors
            %p
                = @recipe.errors.count
                Prevented this recipe from saving.
            %ul
                - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                    %li= msg
    .panel-body
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :image, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        .row
            .col-md-6
                %h3 Ingredients
                #ingredients
                    = f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
                        = render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
                    .links
                        = link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients, class: 'btn btn-default add-button'

    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

**_ingredients_fields.html.haml**

```
.form-inline.clearfix
    .nested-fields
        = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-input form-control' }
        = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: 'form-button btn btn-default'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is called `_ingredients_fields` and it's expecting `_ingredient_fields` (singular ingredient)